Solve simultaneous equation with 3 variable using Vieta relations
Given that complex numbers x, y, z satisfy $x^2=y^2+z-1$, $y^2=z^2+x-1$, $z^2=x^2+y-1$
find the sum of all possible values of $x^2+y^2+z^2$
I was stuck on this question as I tried adding the equations up, resulting in x+y+z=3 and manipulated $(x+y+z)^2$, however, both conclusions did not help solve the question. I asked one of my friends and he said it was related to Vieta. I could not see any way of applying Vieta to this and would appreciate any help or hint!
This question came from P2SC

Welcome to MSE. Which specific competition paper does this come from?

I wonder if this is not related to Cardano

@RedFive This question comes from P2SC

Please [edit] your post to provide the link to the competition where you encountered this, in the post itself (not the comments).

Follow-up query - have the solutions to this contest been released on the website? The link provided says discussing the problems is forbidden until the solutions are released and I suspect posting here is considered discussion. EDIT - problems have been released so discussion is allowed.

From $x+y+z=3$, we deduce then
$$\implies \cases{x^2 =y^2+(3-x-y)-1\\y^2 =z^2+(3-y-z)-1\\z^2 =x^2+(3-z-x)-1}\implies \cases{x^2+x =y^2-y+2\\y^2+y =z^2-z+2\\z^2+z =x^2-x+2}\tag{1}$$
Subtract the first and second equation of $(1)$:
$$(x-y)(x+y+1) = (y-z)(y+z-1)$$
By similar method, we have:
$$\cases{(x-y)(x+y+1) = (y-z)(y+z-1)\\(y-z)(y+z+1) = (z-x)(z+x-1)\\(z-x)(z+x+1) = (x-y)(x+y-1)}\tag{2}$$
If $x = y$, we must have $ (y-z)(y+z-1)= 0$

If $y=z$ then we have $x =y=z=1$ and so $\color{red}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3}$
If $y \ne z \implies y+z = 1 \implies x=2 \implies (x,y,z) = (2,2,-1)$. However, it's easy to verify that $(x,y,z) = (2,2,-1)$ is not the solution of $(1)$

If $x\ne y\ne z\ne x$, from $(2)$ we deduce:
$$\begin{align}
&(x+y+1)(y+z+1)(z+x+1)=(y+z-1)(z+x-1)(x+y-1)\\
\iff&(4-x)(4-y)(4-z) = (2-x)(2-y)(2-z)\\
\iff&2(xy+yz+zx) =12(x+y+z)-56 = -20
\end{align}$$
From $x+y+z = 3$, we deduce then
$$\color{red}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3^2-(-20)=29}$$
Conclusion: the sum of all possible values of $x^2+y^2 + z^2$ is $3+29 = \color{red}{32}$.
